# Executing SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SP_InsertTicket
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    declare @i as numeric
    exec SP_InsertTicket 'asd','cd@y.com','232323','dasasd','sdasdas','01-jan-2010',@i output,'sdas','sdasd','02-jan-2010'
    select @i*/
    @Client_FullName varchar(30),
    @Client_EmailAdd varchar(50),
    @Client_Telephn varchar(15),
    @Ticket_Subject varchar(50),
    @Ticket_Source varchar(15),
    @Ticket_CreateDate Datetime,

    @Ticket_Id integer output,
    @Que_Message varchar(100),
    @Que_Attachment varchar(max),
    @Que_UpdateDate Datetime

AS
    declare @TickID integer;
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    BEGIN

       INSERT INTO tbl_Ticket (Client_FullName,Client_EmailAdd,Client_Telephn,Ticket_Subject,Ticket_Source,Ticket_CreateDate)

                     VALUES (@Client_FullName,  @Client_EmailAdd ,@Client_Telephn,@Ticket_Subject,@Ticket_Source,@Ticket_CreateDate)


        Select @TickID = MAX(Ticket_Id) from tbl_Ticket


        set @Ticket_Id=@TickID

        INSERT INTO tbl_TicketQuestion (Ticket_Id,Que_Message,Que_Attachment,Que_UpdateDate)

                     VALUES (@TickID,@Que_Message,@Que_Attachment,@Que_UpdateDate)

     END

    RETURN
```

---

This is my store procedure in which i need to return Ticket_Id to send it via email app
It insert records well bt not able to retirn value in DAL
Below is the code for executing stored procedure which returns value

```
public class cls_DAL
{
    public cls_DAL()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

   static string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();



  public int insert_NewTicket(string fullname, string emailadd, string telephone, string subject, string source, DateTime date,string Message, string attachment, DateTime updatedate)
  {
      try
      {  
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertTicket", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_FullName", fullname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_EmailAdd", emailadd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_Telephn",telephone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Subject", subject);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Source",source);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_CreateDate",date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Id",0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Que_Message", Message);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Que_Attachment", attachment);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Que_UpdateDate",updatedate);

            cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int i = (int)cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Value;

        }
     catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: you return statement should be after this line. int i = (int)cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Value;

Comment: i need result of select query in DAL class

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Select MAX` but rather `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: ya i've put return statement last.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a guess, not sure. You can give a try the following:

```
cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

TO

```
cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't compile you'll get unreachable code

```
cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (int)cmd.Parameters["@Ticket_Id"].Value;
```

or @Matt's solution below...

That cast is iffy as well...

And in a  multi user scenario, ticketid will race.
Think about what could (will!!!) happen if you run two of these at the same time

Should be wrapped in a transaction.

And you don't need Max, either, Use Scope_Identity

Comment: bt how to use scope_Identity?

Comment: Select @TickID = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY. If you google it you'll learn all about it, and more important the why of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `Select Scope_Identity()` after the Insert statement. Then in your DAL Method `return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())`

Comment: I agree with the first part, but whislt the second part would work I think it unesscessary

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to

```
Int i = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you are only returning one integer from that procedure.

`ExecuteNonQuery()` isnt the method you want to be using here